# C create a PID file non binary

Tags: c, fopen, fwrite, pid

I want to create a function that, given a string filename, creates the file called *filename.PID* inside the *./pid* directory.

```c
    #define DEBUG 1
    //PRINT_DEBUG just print the string in stderr

    int CreatePidFile(char *filename){
    if(DEBUG){
        DEBUG_PRINT("CreatePidFile: start\n");
    }
    char *path = "./pid/";
    char *post = ".PID";
    FILE *pidfile;
    char *pathfilename;
    int N=strlen(path)+strlen(filename)+strlen(post)+1;
    if((pathfilename=(char *)malloc(N*sizeof(char)))==NULL){
        return -3;
    }
    strcpy(pathfilename, path);
    strcat(pathfilename, filename);
    strcat(pathfilename, post);
    pathfilename[N-1]='\0';  //just to be sure that it has the final string char

    if((pidfile = fopen(pathfilename, "w"))==NULL){
        if(DEBUG){
            DEBUG_PRINT("CreatePidFile: impossible to create il file\n");
        }
        free(pathfilename);
        return -1;
    }
    int pid=getpid();

    if((fwrite((void *)&pid, sizeof(int), 1, pidfile))==0){
        if(DEBUG){
            DEBUG_PRINT("CreatePidFile: impossible to write pid in pidfile\n");
        }
        fclose(pidfile);
        free(pathfilename);
        return -2;
    }
    fclose(pidfile);
    free(pathfilename);
    if(DEBUG){
            DEBUG_PRINT("CreatePidFile: end\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The main I use is:

```c
    int main(){
    printf("create pid: start\n");
    char *filepid = "test_pid_file";
    if((CreatePidFile(filepid))!=0){
        printf("file not created\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("test_utility: file is created\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

At the end of the program, the file is created but is a binary file.
I want a text file.

Comment: Use `fprintf()`?

Comment: On a sidenote I must point out that supervising processes by their PID is quite fragile and the whole concept of PID files is more or less broken. PID files are usually employed for programs that daemonize thenself (i.e. detach from the controlling terminal and go to background). Daemonization should never have been invented in the first place, it causes so much trouble, and people had to come up with hacks ( http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/fghack.html ) to reverse its effects for programs that insist on doing so. So if you're implementing PID files so that you can daemonize. Please don't!

Answer (score 4):

Well, you do a binary write of the `pid`:

```
fwrite((void *)&pid, sizeof(int), 1, pidfile)
```

If you want text, just use `fprintf`:

```
fprintf(pidfile, "%d", (int)pid);
```

Comment: And there are excellent reasons to make that a textual file. Since shell scripts could then use it